# What is the valid Javascript syntax for creating an object by using Object Literal Notation?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, object-literal

I'm learning Javascript track in codecademy.com. And I'm confused about creating object by using "Object Literal Notation".

Here [syntax1](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-3bmfN/0/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#), in the hint section the syntax is:

```
var friends = {
    bill: {},
    steve: {}
};
```

We need those curly braces to contain keys' values within the object's curly brace.

BUT, in [syntax2](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-9Sgpi/2/2?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661), the syntax is:

```
var myObject = {
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value
};
```

See, **no** need for curly braces container within  the object's curly brace.
As I did the exercise we only required to: direct input for numbers and functions, or within quotation for strings, or within square brackets for arrays.

Can someone kindly share their knowledge and time to tell me why we have the difference or which one is the correct syntax?

Comment: It's clearly stated: "*Use your friends' names as the keys for the **empty objects**.*"

Comment: @all: Thanks guys, for all your fast respond.
I need some time to understand and try'em.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Object Literal Notation" just means the following format:

```
var myObject = {
    key1: <value1>,
    key2: <value2>,
    // ...
    keyN: <valueN>
};
```

where `<valueX>` can be any JS value, like a boolean, a number, a string or even another Object (which is indicated by the same `{ key1: <value1> ... }` syntax).

An *empty object* is just one that has no keys (properties) and thus looks like `{ }` (space is optional).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what will be the content of your variables:

synthax1:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Thiago",
    currentYear : 2014
};
```

synthax2:

```
    var obj = {
        name: "Thiago",
        skills: {
           key: "JS",
           value: 1
        }

};
```

you can initialize with [] and it will be an array.

Comment: In your haste, you made a syntax error with your "syntax1" example.

Comment: Is the error is equal sign in "currentYear = 2014", Greg ?
Sorry, but i'm happy to know a bit here and there as my learning goes onward.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want the values to be.

`{}` is an empty object; other literals are other values.